# Removing Unique Characters in Different Parts of String

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to cut the ? character and pixels work out of a text file export in a unique column.

Sample String: ?300 dpi

`@{N='Dpi' ; E={$_.'Horizontal resolution'.Split(" ")[0]}}`

I am using split to successfully remove `dpi` although I also want to remove the `?` at the start of the string.

`"Name","Path","BaseName","Dpi","Width(Pixels)","Height(Pixels)","DpiTest"
"test.png","\\directory\TCG\Labels\test.png","test","?300","?2623","?1229","?2623 pixels"`

Comment: If you know you have a ? and dpi in your string just use replace...

`$string -replace '?','' `

Comment: @nkasco using `@{N='TEST' ; E={$_.Width -replace '?', ''}}` still returns ?300

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `TrimStart()` method to remove one or more characters at the start of a string:

```
$_.'Horizontal resolution'.Split(" ")[0].TrimStart('?')
```

But I would suggest using the `-replace` operator for both operations:

```
$_.'Horizontal resolution' -replace '\?(\d+).*','$1'
```

The regex matches on a literal **?**, 1 or more numerical **d**igits and anything, and then replaces it with with the digits

Comment: I am using `@{N='DpiTest' ; E={$_.'Horizontal resolution' -replace '\?(\d+).*','$1'}}` but it still returns ?300 dpi

Comment: And you are sure that the contents of the `Horizontal resolution` property is exactly `?300 dpi`?

Comment: Yes, I have added the first line of the text file in the description (the output)

Answer (score 0):

just do it:

```
$_.'Horizontal resolution'.Split(" ")[0].Replace('?', '')
```